# Is it possible make an xml field non editable in IOS

Tags: ios, xml

I'm trying to look into the possibility to make text field in iOS read only. Let's take the WIFI settings as an example. Here the picture

[image]

I want to make the DNS field read only and if someone wants to click on it, nothing happens, and the fields are coded in xml.

```
<key>DNS</key>
            <dict>
                <key>ServerAddresses</key>
                <array>
                    <string>8.8.8.8</string>
                    <string>8.8.4.4</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
```

Comment: Im sorry but I don't get you :D you want what?

Comment: are you talking about the xml used to build settings for the *ios settings app*?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I want to make the DNS field non editable. Someone cannot edit the field or add anything to it. Is it possible in xml?

Comment: I still don't get it -- for what? what XML? do you use xml to build your app's UI? or what?

Comment: The file that contains the information about the wifi setting is coded in xml and called "Preference.plist". So if I want to make it only read, I have to do it via XML. no?

Comment: no - the xml doesn't make up the user interface it seems

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple as

```
textfieldName.editable = NO;
```

where you set up the text field

it might also be

```
textfieldName.enabled = NO;
```

i can't remember at the moment

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, i was thinking of something else when i wrote the sentence then when i wrote the code

Comment: Where should I add this line? in dict or serveraddress?

Comment: Wherever you setup / add the text to the textfield, i might be wrong on this part but maybe even the viewDidLoad

Comment: I'll try this and see how it goes. Thanks!